# Can a Postgres DB on heroku be restored after delete

Tags: heroku

I have unintentionally deleted my Postgres DB on my heroku "Hobby Dev" instance. Does heroku keep a backup that could be used to restore it?

Answer (score 0):

Hobby databases do not have access to the point-in-time recovery feature that is available on the production tier of databases. If you haven't captured any logical backups with `heroku pg:backups` then there's no way to recover what you've deleted.